# SQL Server authentication and authorization case

Tags: sql-server, authentication, authorization

I've got the following use case.
We want to setup multiple SQL Server 2019 instances which multiple databases. But we're not sure how to setup the server logins and database users.

- We will run a webapplication that can login to the sql server and to the specific customer database. So we're thinking about setting this up in a one to many config. So one login connected to many database users.
- We've got multiple team members that need to access the databases to perform maintenance or analyse data. We don't want to reuse the database user that the webapplication uses. Instead we want to create temporary database users which are granted the needed crud permissions. These are revoked when the team member is done.

But we are unsure how to set this up and if this is a good and secure way of doing this. Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

But we are unsure how to set this up with the SQL server login account roles. Which server role does the SQL server login needs to have? Is the server role [public] enough?

Comment: What are you actually asking here? You define a couple of requirements, and you state you don't know how to achieve this, but you don't ask anything.

Comment: Sounds like maybe you should use Windows Authentication and AD group membership

Comment: @Larnu I tried to state our questions In the OP

Comment: That's 4 questions, @M.Onderwater . Limit your question to a specific question. If you have multiple questions, you need to ask multiple questions. Though things like "Is it best practice" will often be closed as off-topic due to being too opinionated.

Comment: @Larnu ok fair enough, I narrowed it down to a single question for now.